# Operator docstrings displayed on buttons, not in search mode

Tags: python, interface, operator

When hovering over an operator button in blender, a nice box pops up that shows at least the docstring of the operator. However, if I find the same operator with the search function (pressing space in 3dview) and hover over it, no popup is shown.

Why is that? Is there a setting to enable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spacebar search uses `bpy.types.Menu` type class to display content in contrast of `bpy.types.Panel` for buttons etc.

Drawing methods in both of them will be the same, like:

```
def draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(...)
```

Menu will have the items with displayed shortcuts aside with no box popup (this is probably because a menu can have a sub-menu as a popup so to not confuse).

Panel formatting has more options and does show the pop-up doc-string.

This is by some design decision and cannot be changed with current exposed api.